# Android SQLite and Method for it

Tags: android, sqlite

How to declare database in android? How we make a database in android and method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android with sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298898/android-with-sqlite)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you extend a class with [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) and implement `onCreate` and `onUpgrade`.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_table";
    public DatabaseHelper2(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE coordinate (field1 CHAR NOT NULL ,field2 INTEGER NOT NULL ,field3 INTEGER NOT NULL);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO spotit VALUES( test ,10,10);");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
```

Then initiate the class in your main activity.

```
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    db.getReadableDatabase();
    db.close();
```

onCreate will be invoked when you call `db.getReadableDatabase()`

Answer (score 0):

all you need is here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db